# Kafka configuration on existing CDH 5.5.2 cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop2, rhel, cloudera-cdh

I am installing Kafka-2.0 on my existing CDH 5.5.2 cluster, here is the procedure what i followed

1. Add services from CM
2. Selected Kafka (Before that i downloaded and distributes and activated kafka parcel on all the nodes)
3. Selected 1 nodes for KafkaBroker and 4 nodes for Kafka MirrorMaker
4. Then i updated my Destination Broker List (bootstrap.servers) property with one of the Mirror Maker node as well as Source Broker List (source.bootstrap.servers) with same node
5. Below error i am getting (log file)

   ```
   Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown 
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
       at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
       at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
       at kafka.log.SkimpyOffsetMap.<init>(OffsetMap.scala:43)
       at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.<init>(LogCleaner.scala:186)
       at kafka.log.LogCleaner$$anonfun$1.apply(LogCleaner.scala:83)
       at kafka.log.LogCleaner$$anonfun$1.apply(LogCleaner.scala:83)
       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
       at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:166)
       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
       at kafka.log.LogCleaner.<init>(LogCleaner.scala:83)
       at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:64)
       at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createLogManager(KafkaServer.scala:601)
       at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:180)
       at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
       at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
       at com.cloudera.kafka.wrap.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:76)
       at com.cloudera.kafka.wrap.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

you need to increase `broker_max_heap_size` value to atleast **1GB** and restart the kafka service from Cloudera Manager. If you still face the same issue, try to increase as per your cluster configurations

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" - VM heap is running out of space. Increase it by setting

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms512M"
```

in /bin/kafka-server-start.sh.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, ya i check it. It was 20 MB only, then i changed to cdh default value i.e 256 MB. Now Kafka Broker installation is done, but Kafka MirrorMaker is not starting